# Reassign Guest Orders in Magento?

Tags: magento2, orders

Running Magento 2.1.2

Is there any way in Magento 2 to assign orders to main customer accounts, as lately my customer placed a guest order and asked me to reassign this order to the main account?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/magepal/magento2-guest-to-customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an extension for magento 2 the following one may help to assign orders - https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-reassign-order.html It adds a button in order for admin to change the order owner.

Answer (score 2):

By using some mysql queryies, you **`can reassign guest orders to customer`**.

Magento save relation between **customer and order** in **`sales_order` table and `sales_order_grid`** table by using **`customer_id`** column.

In Order to assign you need a order to customer, you need run below query

> ```
> update sales_order set customer_id = [YOUR_Customer_Id], customer_is_guest=
> 0 where entity_id=[Your_order_id]
>
>
>
>
> update sales_order_grid set customer_id = [YOUR_Customer_Id]
> where entity_id=[Your_order_id]
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. But it would be great to automate it in future if we have the same issue again. Do you have an idea if there any module for that?

Comment: but, also please check @marius explainaton

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one time only thing you can just find the customer id you need and update the order record from `sales_order` table by setting the field `customer_id` to the value you found above.
If you want a long time automated version is not that easy and I don't have a solution for it.